# Group sum from two tables according to date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, sum

I have two different tables, lead and click. I would like to query MySQL to get the sum of the commissions generated by clicks and leads ordered by date.

**Lead:**

```
id|date      |commission
 1|2009-06-01|400
 2|2009-06-01|300
 3|2009-06-03|350
```

**Click:**

```
id|date      |commission
 1|2009-06-01|1
 2|2009-06-03|2
 3|2009-06-03|1
```

I would like to create a query that gives me (and if possible also gets date where no lead or click has been generated):

```
date      |commission click|commission lead|total commission
2009-06-01|               1|            700|             701
2009-06-02|               0|              0|               0
2009-06-02|               3|            350|             353
```

(The date is actually datetime in the real database.)

I guess I have to combine:

```
SELECT count(*) as number_clicks, sum(click.commission) as sum_clicks,
 date(click.time) as click_date from click group by click_date order by click_date
```

With:

```
SELECT count(*)as number_leads, sum(lead.commission) as sum_leads,
 date(lead.time) as lead_date from lead group by lead_date order by lead_date
```

But I can not get them to work together.

Comment: Why am I editing ancient questions? Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't get dates with zeroes, for that you'll either need a dates table or a stored procedure to loop through dates. One way to do it is a subselect from a union query (untested):

```
SELECT commission_date, SUM(click_commission), SUM(lead_commission), SUM(total_commission)
FROM (SELECT DATE(click.time) AS commission_date, click.commission AS click_commission,
             0 AS lead_commission, click.commission AS total_commission
      FROM click
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE(lead.time) AS commission_date, 0 AS click_commission,
             lead.commission AS lead_commission, lead.commission AS total_commission
      FROM lead) AS foo
GROUP BY commission_date
ORDER BY commission_date
```

Comment: Got "Every derived table must have its own alias " but after adding "AS foo" after the last SELECT and before GROUP it worked just as asked. Thanks!